# Assign a value to a boolean variable in loop * ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a ngFor loop in my component `window-container`where I have several chat window (`window-item`) that are displayed. I want to set a variable (`changeColor`) to true for one div on two, and false for the other div on two.
I want to be able to use this variable in both components : `window-container` and `window-item`.

This is what I did in `window-container.html` but it does not work :

```
<window-item
  *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index"
    [thread]="thread">
      <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 0"> {{this.threadService.changeColor = false}}</div>
      <div *ngIf="i % 2 != 0"> {{this.threadService.changeColor = true}}
    </div>
</window-item>
```

I want that the variable `changeColor` change value for each div for write this in my `window-item.html` :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'window-grey' : !this.threadService.changeColor, 'window-blue': this.threadService.changeColor}">
    <div class="panel-container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `window-item.scss` :

```
.panel-heading {
   .top-bar {
      .window-grey {
         background: grey;
      }
      .window-grey {
         background: grey;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use it like :**

> Would suggest you should pass that via `odd` / `even` of `ngFor`
>
> **even**: boolean: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
>
> **odd**: boolean: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

```
<window-item
  *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index ; let odd = odd;"
    [thread]="{ thread : thread , changeColor : odd }">
      <!-- <div *ngIf="i % 2 == 0"> {{this.threadService.changeColor = false}} </div>
      <div *ngIf="i % 2 != 0"> {{this.threadService.changeColor = true}} </div> -->
</window-item>

// window-item.html
<div [ngClass]="{'window-grey' : !changeColor, 'window-blue': changeColor}">
    <div class="panel-container">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-odd-even)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work. I have no window that opens

Comment: what about make a @input "odd" < window-item
  *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index ; let odd = odd;"
    [thread]="thread" [odd]="odd">< /window-item>

Comment: @Eliseo Where do I write `@input "odd` ? In `window-container.component.ts` ?

Comment: @user9099802 , yes

Comment: I think your window-item is a "child" of "window-container". I think you're using @input to pass [thread] :(

Comment: It puts me this error : `Can't bind to 'odd' since it isn't a known property of 'window-item'.
1. If 'window-item' is an Angular component and it has 'odd' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'window-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    *ngFor="let thread of windows; let i = index; let odd = odd;"
    [thread]="thread"
    [ERROR ->][odd] = "odd">`

Comment: @user9099802 , please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngfor-odd-even , I think demo will clear all your doubts

Comment: @VivekDoshi I don not understand why I still not work for me. I think it's in my `window-container.html`

Comment: @Eliseo I understood my mistake! Elisea's solution works. Thank you for your help :)